# How to iterate dict in string.format

Tags: python, string.format

I read a lot of tutorials, but can not find how to iterate dict in string.format like this:

```py
dict = {'this':'I','is':'am','title':'done'}
print(f'the key is {k for k,v in dict}')
print(f'the val is {v for k,v in dict}')
```

which I want a result like this:

```
the key is this is title
the val is I am done
```

so I can print variable length dict.

```
dict = {'this':'I','is':'am','title':'done'}
print(f'the key is {k for k,v in dict}')
print(f'the val is {v for k,v in dict}')
```

Then I got error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your output is:

```
the key is <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fbaca5443c0>
the val is <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fbaca5443c0>
```

That's because `k for k,v in dict` is a generator expression. Don't confuse it with *set comprehension*, those curly braces are for f-string.

But of course that `k for k,v in dict` is problematic. When you iterate over a dictionary itself, it gives you keys. So for the first iteration `"this"` comes back. you can't unpack `"this"` into two variables. `k, v = "this"`.

You can use this:

```py
d = {"this": "I", "is": "am", "title": "done"}
print(f'the key is {" ".join(d.keys())}')
print(f'the val is {" ".join(d.values())}')
```

output:

```
the key is this is title
the val is I am done
```

This `join` works because keys and values are strings in your dictionary. If they are not, you should convert them like:

```py
print(f'the key is {" ".join(map(str, d.values()))}')
```

For the first one you could also use `print(f'the key is {" ".join(d)}')` as dictionaries will give keys in the iteration by default.

Comment: @FL.S For that use: `print(f'the key is {" ".join(map(repr, d.keys()))}')`

Answer (score 0):

I would do this, if you don't mind having a space at the end I'm no expert tho:

```
mydict = {"this": "I", "is": "am", "title": "done"}


def get_str(dict):
    str_a = ""
    str_b = ""
    for k in dict:
        str_a += f"{k} "
        str_b += f"{dict[k]} "
    print(str_a)
    print(str_b)


get_str(mydict)
```

output:

```
this is title 
I am done
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`print("The keys are", ' '.join(k for k in dict))` for the keys

`print("The keys are", ' '.join(v for k, v in dict.items()))` for the values